# I can't run vue cli in Ubuntu - Error: Unable to access jarfile /snap/vue/1/jar/vue-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Tags: vue.js, ubuntu, vue-cli

I am trying to install vue cli for the first time.

I tried using `npm install -g @vue/cli` and `yarn global add @vue/cli` and it seems to install correctly.

But if I run `vue create my-project` or `vue --version`, I get the following error:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~18.04-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
Error: Unable to access jarfile /snap/vue/1/jar/vue-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

My operative system is Ubuntu.

Comment: I got the same error from having run "sudo snap install vue" beforehand, which installs some Java package called "Visual Understanding Environment" (not vue js). Not sure if this is what you did, but try uninstalling that package if you did? Otherwise just restart/refresh your environment and try again. Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks kylew I'll try

Comment: I just had to open a new tab after vue cli installation. All works fine, am using ubuntu

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem, to solve:

1. Remove the vue using snap

```
sudo snap remove vue
```

2. Then install vue globally via npm or yarn

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

**OR**

```
yarn global add @vue/cli
```

Comment: If you do this and still can not run the `vue` command, you most likely need to prefix it with `npx` for node binaries to be in scope

Instead of `vue create hello-world`, use `npx vue create hello-world` then.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem as mentioned but it's due to me not giving administrator privilege to the installation. Therefore, I had to give an administrator privilege to the installation by typing:

```
sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Then when I need to create the Vue project I type

```
sudo vue create <project_name>
```

and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I used these commands:

```
sudo snap remove vue
sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Then created the Vue project:

```
sudo vue create <project_name>
```

Comment: Thanks man!!!!!

Comment: you're welcome. i'm happy for you

Answer (score 2):

let's try `sudo snap remove vue` you will get something like: "vue removed",
then try: `vue` in the terminal and see if it works ! h

Comment: ps: the reason for my part was a bad java alias, when installing with snap

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me on my Ubuntu system:

npm:

```
sudo snap remove vue && npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Yarn:

```
sudo snap remove vue && yarn global add @vue/cli
```

Then reopen your terminal.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed that using the `vue-init` command rather than `vue init` (which I've read that was the correct one). The entire command used was:

`vue-init webpack-simple your-project-name`

Then Vue-cli will ask you a series of questions such as project name, description and author.

Hope that helps.

Comment: to create vue project like as this method,vue must be installed